# Расположить divы в таблицу в 4 столбца

Tags: html, css

Есть скрипт, который выводит список всех врачей. Вот как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот, например, блок "Д" и блок "И" расположены друг под другом, хотя "И" должен переноситься в начало новой строки. Т.е. нужно, чтобы выглядело как таблица в 4 столбца.

Ниже код.

```
<div class="category" style="margin-top:10px;">
<?$doctor_category = $this->pages_model->get_doctor_category();?>
<?$i=0;?>

<?php foreach ($doctor_category as $item):?>

<div style="float: left; overflow: hidden;  width: 250px; margin-right:20px; border:1px solid red;" class="menu_vipad_1_subcategory_1">
<ul>
    <li class="li_h"><?echo $item['title']?></li>
        <?$doctor = $this->pages_model->get_doctor_by_category($item['id']);?>
        <?php foreach ($doctor as $item1):?>
    <li><a href="#"><?echo $item1['title']?></a></li>
<? endforeach;?>        
</ul>
</div>

<? endforeach;?> 
</div>
```

На php код можете не обращать внимание.

Как сделать так что бы `div`ы были в ряд?

Comment: в вашем случае можно задать `margin` снизу, тогда проблема должна уйти. а вообще можно использовать display: flex для родителя и тогда можно их будет выстроить в ряд

Comment: margin не подойдет, потому что я незнаю сколько врачей будет в будущем, нужно что то универсальное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант подойдет?

Главное: `display: table;` на родительском диве + `display: table-cell; float: left;` на детях + `div:nth-child(4n+1)`, чтобы после каждого четвертого `div` новая строка начиналась.

```css
.main {
  display: table;
}
.main>div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.main>div:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>block 1</div>
  <div>block 2</div>
  <div>block 3
    <br>with line break</div>
  <div>block 4</div>
  <div>block 5</div>
  <div>block 6
    <br>with line break</div>
  <div>block 7</div>
  <div>block 8</div>
  <div>block 9</div>
  <div>block 10</div>
  <div>block 11</div>
  <div>block 12</div>
  <div>block 13</div>
  <div>block 14</div>
  <div>block 15
    <br>with line break</div>
</div>
```

Comment: а для чего `display: table;` и `display: table-cell;`? Не достаточно просто блоков с флоатами и clear:left у каждого 4n+1? https://jsfiddle.net/bssm9drc/1/